# tokenization of variable in java netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans-8

how to tokenize the variables,
constants, class, method names as a special token ‘$’ in java.

```
try {
    int ch;
    boolean slashCommentFound = false;
    boolean starCommentFound = false;
    boolean firstSlashFound = false;
    boolean startOfComment = false;
    boolean endOfComment = false;
    boolean startDoubleQuoteFound = false;
    StringBuilder javaDoc = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "D://abc.txt"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            "D:\\abc1.txt"));

    while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
        javaDoc.append((char) ch);

        if (ch == '\"')
            startDoubleQuoteFound = !startDoubleQuoteFound;

        if (startDoubleQuoteFound
                && (starCommentFound == true || slashCommentFound == true))
            continue;

        if (ch == '/') {
            if (starCommentFound == true && endOfComment == false)
                continue;

            if (endOfComment && starCommentFound == true) {
                starCommentFound = false;
                endOfComment = false;
                startOfComment = false;
                continue;
            }

            else if (firstSlashFound && slashCommentFound == false
                    && starCommentFound == false) {
                slashCommentFound = true;
                firstSlashFound = false;
                continue;
            }

            else if (slashCommentFound == false
                    && starCommentFound == false
                    && startDoubleQuoteFound == false) {
                firstSlashFound = true;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (ch == '*') {
            if (starCommentFound) {
                endOfComment = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (firstSlashFound && starCommentFound == false) {
                starCommentFound = true;
                firstSlashFound = false;
                continue;
            }

            else if (startOfComment == false
                    && starCommentFound == true) {
                startOfComment = true;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (ch == '\n') {
            if (slashCommentFound) {
                slashCommentFound = false;
                startOfComment = false;
                firstSlashFound = false;
                starCommentFound = false;
                out.print((char) ch);
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (starCommentFound == true && endOfComment == false)
            continue;

        String doc = javaDoc.toString();

        if (doc.trim().startsWith("/**") && doc.trim().endsWith("*/")) {
            // out.print(javaDoc.toString());
            javaDoc = new StringBuilder();
        }

        if (ch != '/' && ch != '*') {
            if (endOfComment)
                System.out.print((char) ch);

            endOfComment = false;
            firstSlashFound = false;
            startOfComment = false;
            endOfComment = false;
        }

        if (slashCommentFound == false && starCommentFound == false) {
            javaDoc = new StringBuilder();
            // out.print( ( char ) ch );
        }
        buffer.append((char) ch);
        writer.write((char) ch);
    }
    fileOutput = buffer.toString();
    reader.close();
    writer.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: input is file and i want tokenize this file with $

Comment: int aa,b,c;
c=aa+b;
cout<<c; this is input and i want $,$,$;
$=$+$;
cout<<$;

Comment: please send me code in java